# Calculating Checkout Conversion using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the checkout conversion by using the following query but I keep getting error:

```sql
SELECT
 (SELECT seller.name, count(checkout.id) AS 'Completed_checkout'
    FROM checkout
         JOIN seller
         ON seller.id = checkout.seller_id
   WHERE checkout.completed = 1
   GROUP BY seller.name)
/
  (SELECT seller.name, count(checkout.id) AS 'Total_Checkouts'
     FROM checkout
          JOIN seller
          ON seller.id = checkout.seller_id
    GROUP BY seller.name) * 100 
AS 'Checkout_Converstion';
```

The end goal after being able to calculate it is:

- filter by seller with more than 15 checkouts total
- order it by DESC
- limit it by then 5 first records

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: "I keep getting error" is not a problem description, so [edit] your question to include it, verbatim.

Comment: For one, you can't usually divide subqueries by each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simplifying this?

```
SELECT s.name, AVG(co.completed) as completed_ratio
FROM checkout co JOIN
     seller s
     ON s.id = co.seller_id
GROUP BY s.name;
```

If you want the counts:

```
SELECT s.name, AVG(co.completed = 1) as completed_ratio,
       SUM(c.completed = 1) as num_completed,
       COUNT(*) as total
FROM checkout co JOIN
     seller s
     ON s.id = co.seller_id
GROUP BY s.name;
```

These make use of the fact that MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers in a numeric context -- with "1" for true and "0" for false.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 1 query:

```
SELECT s.name, 
       100 * AVG(c.completed) AS Checkout_Conversion
FROM checkout c JOIN seller s
ON s.id = c.seller_id
GROUP BY s.id, s.name
HAVING SUM(c.completed) > 15
ORDER BY Checkout_Conversion DESC
LIMIT 5
```